# React Native - multiple targets

Tags: xcode, react-native, target

I'm creating a RN app that is meant to be some kind of wrapper. It should have multiple targets (like in Xcode) and all its content (images, text, etc.) should be target dependent. Unfortunately, I cannot find any useful informations about how to achieve this without opening Xcode or Android Studio project and create those targets manually (like [here](https://medium.com/@jacks205/adding-multiple-target-pipelines-for-react-native-apps-and-fastlane-circleci-deployment-pt-1-ae9590ae52f2)). Is there any other solutions for this?

Comment: There is no way of doing what you ask. If you need addition Xcode targets or Android Studio flavours, you need to use those tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was still struggling with described problem but I finally found a solution. It's not easy, needs writing a bit of boilerplate code and looks more like a workaround but I hope it will help someone in the future. What I did is I have completed my wrapper app with the resources for one of my targets so I can have visual effect. In the project's root directory I've created a folder with subfolders for each target. Inside each I have put files (images, source code files, other assets) that are target-dependent. Then I've created bash script that takes one argument - target's name. Based on it, it replaces all the target-dependent files from target's subfolder to the original file's destination in the project structure. In this proces all meta-data informations are also replaced so after firing .sh file I can build the app and upload it to both stores. It's really time consuming to create all these apps separately and publish them and it's maybe not the best solution, but at least it works!

Answer (score -1):

On android, you can edit build.gradle files, java or properties, without having to launch Android Studio (which simply uses Gradle)

You can build [different type flavours](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) by only changing app/build.gradle

On iOS, that's another story. Project file (.pbxproj) is a mess,and other Workspace/Scheme files are not easy to read or script. So XCode is the way to Go.

I tried to have dynamic target & Info.plist, there are tools to script that [like PlistBuddy](https://medium.com/@marksiu/what-is-plistbuddy-76cb4f0c262d)

in the end, I saw there are many ways to launch a React Native app for developpers. Some prefer the command line, and only VSCode.
Others want to play with native IDE.

By the way, native IDEs are VERY useful.
e.g. : you want to fine-tune your application performance, [using XCode view hierarchy debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) or [android Studio Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) (and be sure you don't use to many views), or use any other performance tools these IDEs offer...

In the end, I used react-native-config along with multiple almost similar configs (Info.plist < target < Scheme for each), here's [a post giving an overview of the setup](https://medium.com/@jacks205/adding-multiple-target-pipelines-for-react-native-apps-and-fastlane-circleci-deployment-pt-1-ae9590ae52f2).